# Custom UIBarButtonItem for UIToolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, class-method

In my testing project, I am planning to have multiple picker views. For these picker views, there will be UIToolbars and custom UIBarButtons. I tried to create a class method so that I will not have to repeat the codes, but it seems like the button is not showing up.

**Picker Done Button.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIBarButtonItem (test)
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItemWithTint:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)itemTitle andTarget:(id)theTarget andSelector:(SEL)selector;
@end
```

**Picker Done Button.m**

```
#import "PickerDoneButton.h"

@implementation UIBarButtonItem (test)
+ (UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItemWithTint:(UIColor*)color andTitle:(NSString*)itemTitle andTarget:(id)theTarget andSelector:(SEL)selector
{
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.tintColor = color;
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [button addTarget:theTarget action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    return doneButton;
}
@end
```

And to use this class method on my View Controller.m (I am omitting picker view methods which come after viewDidLoad)

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "PickerDoneButton.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *numberofPeople;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPickerView *countPeople;
@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.countPeople = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    self.countPeople.dataSource = self;
    self.countPeople.delegate = self;
    self.numberofPeople = @[@"1",@"2",@"3"];

    UIToolbar *countPeopleToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,50)];
    countPeopleToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
    // Call the UIBarButtonItem from PickerDoneButton.h
    countPeopleToolbar.items = @[[UIBarButtonItem barButtonItemWithTint:[UIColor redColor] andTitle:@"Done" andTarget:self andSelector:@selector(doneClicked)]];
    [self pickerView:self.countPeople didSelectRow:0 inComponent:0];
}
```

Am I using the class method correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are doing it correct. Only thing you are missing is you are not setting frame of your `button` to be set inside `doneButton`. Since button doesn't have any frame set it doesn't show up. Add this after creating button.

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30); // change frame as per your requirement
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that... Thank you for your help